# Get value from an array using regex in php

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have an array and I want to extract value from that array.
My array is :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => {:en}5:10am
           12:00pm
           {:}{:it}10:10am
           11:00pm{:}
)
```

If **":en"** match result should be 5:10am 12:00pm and for **italian(:it)** result should be 10:10am 11:00pm. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Could you please clarify? What code have you already written? Please share, it will help understand what your are after.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear.. as far as i got the question the ans is as follows
If you are using php u can access array as follows

```
<?php
$time = array(":en"=>"5:10am 12:00pm", ":"=>"", ":it"=>"10:10am 11:00pm");
echo "English  " . $time[':en'] . " Italian  " . $time[':it'];
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert Zero Index value into string and string will be appear like this **"{:en}5:10 12:00 {:}{:it}5:10 12:00{:}"**. After that you can extract substring from an string.

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
        $string = ' ' . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($ini == 0) return '';
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string, $ini, $len);
    }

    $fullstring = '{:en}5:10 12:00 {:}{:it}5:10 12:00{:}';
    $value = get_string_between($fullstring, '{:en}', '{:}');

    echo $value;
```

Comment: Is it an answer? I'd delete the question in this case.